# codeigniter- display image in user pick

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am new to codeigniter. i want to to show a image at user pick. but my result is word instead of image. anyone can help me?

view:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td style=border:hidden><a href="?item=apple"><br /><img src ="http://localhost/image/apple.png" alt="apple" width="100px" height="50px"></a></td>
<td style=border:hidden><a href="?item=orange"><br /><img src ="http://localhost/image/orange.png" alt="orange" width="100px" height="50px" style="margin-top:10px"></a></td>
<td style=border:hidden><a href="?item=grape"><br /><img src ="http://localhost/image/grape.png" alt="grape" width="100px" height="50px" style="margin-top:10px"></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

controller:

```
$userItem = $_GET['item'];
echo "You Picked:" $userItem ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$userItem = $_GET['item'];
echo "You Picked: <img src ='http://localhost/image/" . $userItem . ".png'/>";
```